# Правильная таблица умножения

Tags: c++

Как сделать так, чтобы переменная number в цикле оставляла свое значение, которое будет введено с клавиатуры?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   unsigned long number;
   int i = 1;
   cout << " Enter the number: ";
   cin >> number;
   while (4294967295 > i)
   {
       number *= i;
       cout <<setw(10)<< number;
       i++;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не присваивать ей новое значение. Результат умножения записывать в другую переменную.

Comment: Кстати, какая у вас разрядность? 4294967295 - это 0xffffffff. Многовато для int.

Comment: Написана чушь. Если константа `4294967295` не помещается в `int`, она будет расценена как `long int` или `long long int` и сравнение будет делаться в рамках этого типа. Это будет означать что условие цикла всегда будет истинно и цикл - бесконечен. Единственная надежда на завершаемость такого цикла - это "допотопный" компилятор языка С89/90 (именно С!), который может расценить `4294967295` как `unsigned int`, а также переведет `i` в `-1` после переполнения. Но завязываться на такие совпадения - выходящий за все мыслимые и немыслимые рамки гамнокодинг, не говоря уже о том, что здесь - С++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы, наверное, хотите этого?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned long number;
    cout << " Enter the number > 0: ";
    cin >> number;
    for(unsigned long i = 1; i < 0xFFFFFFFF/number; ++i)
    {
        cout
            << number << " * "
            << setw(15) << i << " = "
            << i*number << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ввести другую переменную :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   unsigned long number, n;
   int i = 1;
   cout << " Enter the number: ";
   cin >> number;
   n = number;
   while (4294967295 > i)
   {
       n *= i;
       cout <<setw(10)<< n;
       i++;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Только скажите мне, а что вы хотите получить? у вас с циклом проблема получается - `int` ведь больше 2 с небольшим миллиардов не достигнет, переполнится и уйдет в -1...

Ну, а результат умножения переполнится гораздо раньше - если только вы вводите не 0, конечно :) Но по достижении должного количества двоек среди множителей `i` результат умножения уйдет в нули.

Что на самом деле требуется вычислить?

Comment: @Abyx Формально да, но, скажем так, не встречал пока, где бы это было иначе...

Comment: Прошу прощения, но мне кажется ваше исправление ничего не изменит. Можно сделать внутри цикла так : n = number * i;

Comment: @Владислав Ваше исправление изменит смысл программы. Поскольку вы так и не написали, что же именно вы хотите получить, говорить о правильности того или иного решения, не понимая конечной цели, совершенно бессмысленно.

Comment: @Harry: Наоборот, абсолютно все современные компиляторы будут генерировать код в предположении, что `i` никогда не может стать `-1`. Это называется strict overflow semantics. Это во-первых. А во-вторых в С++ даже если `i` и станет вдруг `-1` после переполнения, это все равно не нарушит соотношения `4294967295 > i`, т.е. в любом случае цикл - бесконечен.

Comment: @AnT Практика - критерий истины? :) вот что делает компилятор VC++ 2015 - генерирует  `inc esi
 cmp esi, -1
 jb SHORT $LL2@main`. Выливается это в `2147483644
2147483645
2147483646
2147483647
-2147483648
-2147483647
-2147483646
.... -4
-3
-2` и на этом цикл завершается.
Несовременный он какой-то...

Comment: @Harry: Практика - это способ отлова багов в компиляторе. Берем VC2017, делаем `std::cout << typeid(4294967295).name() << std::endl;`. Получаем вывод: `unsigned long`. Ай-яй-яй-яй-яй... Грубейший, постыднейший баг компилятора VC2017 (как, очевидно, и VS2015). В языке С++ бессуффиксный десятичный литерал не может быть беззнаковым, если он помещается в знаковый целый тип из ряда `int`, `long`, `long long`. VC2017 уже поддерживает 64-битный `long long`. Если мне память не изменяет, VS2015 тоже поддерживал.

Comment: Единственное оправдание такому поведению - это то, что VS2015 и VC2017 поддерживают `long long` в качестве расширения, но "официально" не признают этот тип частью ядра языка. В такой ситуации, при 32-битных `int` и `long`, сам факт наличия в программе литерала `4294967295` приводит к неопределенному поведению. А в случае UB, как понимаете, возможно все. Тогда, в рамках этой лазейки, этот цикл "работает" только за счет удачного совпадения двух независимых проявлений UB: 1) литерал `4294967295` породил беззнаковое значение, 2) переполнившийся знаковый `int` "завернулся".

Comment: Однако VC2017 утверждает какую-то поддержку С++14. И дальнейший эксперимент с `std::cout << typeid(4294967296).name() << std::endl;` (всего на единичку больше) вдруг выдает `__int64`! То есть `long long`. Таким образом становится ясно, что интерпретация `4294967295` как беззнакового значения - это не лихая свобода в рамках UB, а банальный баг компилятора VC++, который вы и поймали/подтвердили своей "практикой".

Comment: @AnT А как же *абсолютно все современные компиляторы будут генерировать код в предположении, что i никогда не может стать -1.*? :) Я, конечно, не ожидал, что VC++ сделает цикл не бесконечным, но с вами я несогласен в другом - что с int'ом у какого-то компилятора не будет перехода из плюсов в минуса - тоже (ваше *переполнение int это UB, -1 может и не быть*). Я ошибся в том, что имел в виду не -1, а наименьшее значение (0x80000000), но как и писал (*Формально да, но, скажем так, не встречал пока, где бы это было иначе...*), платформы, где это не так, не только не видел, но и не слышал.

Comment: @Harry: Во-первых, "будут компилировать" - это еще 1) вопрос 
правильной настройки параметров компиляции: strict overflow semantics пока что обычно является отключаемой оптимизацией, 2) вопрос общего случая: в общем случае надо рассчитывать, что будут, хоть в некоторых частных могут и не, 3) вопрос правильной работы компилятора: мое утверждение, разумеется, не покрывает явные баги компиляторов. Что касается "не видел и не слышал" - поведение GCC при выполнении strict oveflow semantics именно в таких ситуациях уже наделало столько шуму, что я не предполагал, что кто-то мог о нем не слышать.